# working from home, can they monitor my other computers

Tags: privacy

I work from home on my own desktop. The company I work for has me use a keyfob and six digit number to synchronize with their servers. they can monitor me and warned me they do monitor as well as the phone used through the computer.

can they monitor me when I have the keyfob out and I am using the computer for personal use after I have signedout.

also are my other laptops and computer in the house safe? or can they monitor that as well?

Comment: Do you plug the keyfob into the computer or just read a number from it?

Comment: this is a question for your company's IT support - we don't know what they do to monitor you